# How to get objects if user is in a field of another django model's many-to-many field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
...

class Node(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    collaborators = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

What I'm trying to do is get all projects where the user requesting the page is part of a node within the project.

For example:
If there are projects A, B, C, D and the requesting user is a collaborator on nodes within projects A and D, projects A and D would be returned (preferably with the ability to access those nodes as well).

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Project.objects.filter(node__collaborators=my_user)
```

Comment: This works as expected, but I forgot another key part: Project also has a project_collaborators field that contains users as well, I'd also like to filter by that, but the user may not necessarily be a project collaborator if they are a node collaborator. I tried `Project.objects.filter(node__collaborators=my_user,project_collaborators=my_user)`, but that just filtered by node collaborators AND project collaborators, where I'm looking for it to filter by node collaborators OR project collaborators. Any help on that?

Comment: Use the Q (`from django.db.models import Q`) queries and the pipe `|` for logical OR. `Project.objects.filter(Q(node__collaborators=my_user) | Q(project_collaborators=my_user‌​))`

Comment: That worked well, but now it's returning one project if you're a collaborator of it, and another if you're a collaborator on a node within the project. Any way to add a distinct clause to that, or something similar? Also, is there a way to select all nodes of the project if the user is a project collaborator, and only the nodes the user is a collaborator of if they're not a project collaborator?

Comment: This is starting to look like you need two queries. `nodes = Project.objects.filter(node__collaborators=my_user)` and `projects = Project.objects.filter(project_collaborators=my_user‌​)`. Then you can do something like `users = User.objects.filter(Q(id__in=node_collborators) | Q(id_in=project_collaborators))` This will give you a distinct group of users. Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but hopefully it helps. I am not sure you can do what you are trying to do in one line. FYI: there is a way to get distinct like `Project.objects.values('node__collaborators').distinct()`.